# BD8306MUV and idle current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck-boost, power-consumption, idle

I need to generate 3.3 V from a 3.6 V battery to power a sensor. I choose the Rohm buck-boost converter [BD8306MUV](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/switching_regulator/bd8306muv-e.pdf) for that, but I discovered that it consumes nearly 5 mA of current in idle mode without a load. The circuit is as recommended by the manufacturer. A novice question; Is this normal, or do I have an error somewhere?

**Schematic:**

[image]

Comment: Where in the datasheet do you read 5 mA?

Comment: @MiNiMe No .. datasheet says 500 uA, but in real life I get 5 mA. I measured it without any load in the output .. that is someway strange.

Comment: In the schematic, the thermal pad is connected to RT, is it a mistake? Datasheet does not say anything at all about the pad, so I doubt it should be connected.

Comment: @MiNiMe no -- thermal pad is connected to the ground. In the reference schematic and PCB layout is thermal pad also connected to the ground.

Comment: My mistake, let me rephrase - Is the pad supposed to be connected to any of the circuit at all? Datasheet doesn't mention it as pin 17, or gives that it should be connected to GND.

Comment: Actually I don't know -- the reference PCB has it connected to the ground -- I toke that as reference for my PCB and schematic.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but still it looks like it's connected to a copper pour for thermal purpose, and that seems not to be connected to the ground plane. So *maybe*, that's where your milliamps disappear.

Comment: Actually, there's multiple connections to GND through vias. Unless someone with more knowledge than me can give a satisfactory answer to this, you could reach out to ROHM directly.

Comment: Only change I did to the original schematic is the inductor -- I did not get the Toko DEM3518C and replaced it with Murata LQH3NPZ4R7MGRL -- would that be the culprit?

Comment: Could be. I did a search for that Toko part number, and it turns up as Murata now, I guess Murata bought Toko. This is what I found: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Electronics/1231AS-H-4R7M%3dP3?qs=4tuKoHGzn13BmDv7vMjxCw%3D%3D

Comment: Yeah they are very different, I added both parts for a comparison at Mouser. Can't say for sure if this is the issue with your circuit though.

Comment: Ok .. I try to replace with more similar part with the same size as my part right now is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this normal, or do I have an error somewhere?

Looks normal to me.

Apparently, you copied the first application circuit given on the p.11 of the datasheet. There are some performance graphs on p.13 and onwards. The efficiency graph shows an efficiency of 13~14% for 1 mA output current when the input is 3.7 VDC. This is close to your case for comparison. Now let's work out the input current at this "minimum" load:

$$
\eta=0.13 = \frac{3.3 \cdot 0.001}{3.7 \cdot I_{in}} \Rightarrow I_{in}=6.9 \ \text{mA}
$$

1 mA and idle (zero load) are different things but should be enough to give an idea:

For 3.3 mW of output power (3.3V - 1 mA) the circuit consumes roughly 25 mW, according to the performance graphs. Now let's think straightforward: If we assume the 3.3 mW is transferred to the output with no extra loss then the input power at exactly zero load (idle) would be 25 - 3.3 = 21.5 mW, making the input current roughly 6 mA.

So it looks normal to see 5 mA input current at zero load.

Comment: I think that is the case. I choosed just wrong chip with too large standby current for battery operation. Thanks for looking at the problem.